# Android Studio: Rename SharedPreferences File

Tags: android, file, sharedpreferences, rename, explorer

First of all: I am new to Android.
I have created a SharedPreferences File to save the answers of a poll.
Now I want to rename this SharedPreferences File so that I can save the votes of many People.
The device is rooted, so I could rename the file with Root Explorer, but thats not cool.

Please Help :)

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose it would be much better to use SQLite database.
Here you can find everything that you need: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).
SharedPreferences should be used for the data that will be used by the app.